# Adding javascript function to a grocerycrud add or edit form

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

Is it possible to add a javascript function to the add/edit forms of grocery_CRUD?

E.g. As a user is typing in a particular field when adding or editing a record I want to execute a javascript on the keydown event.

If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible.
For example, you call the view like this:

```
$this->load->view('grocery_crud_view', $output);
```

In the beginning of the view (grocery_crud_view.php), you can add any javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascrpt">
    $("#field-code").keyup(function(){
       alert("there is a keyup");
    });
</script>
<?php
// The rest of default php code
?>
```

Most of the id of the grocery-CRUD view (if you use flexigrid theme) would be something like this : "field-your_field_name"
You can inspect with firebug or google-chrome developer tools to ensure it.